# 32bit and 64bit Cygwin sshd services on the same machine

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, sshd, jenkins

I have Windows 7 station and I would like to have two running sshd services:

- ssh daemon for 32bit Cygwin
- ssh daemon for 64bit Cygwin

I installed *32bit Cygwin sshd* using setup script **ssh-host-config**.

Then I edited script (changed name service) and installed *64bit cygwin sshd*.
I'm able to start both services (of course using different port numbers).

32bit sshd works just fine but 64bit sshd is not working well or rather is acting weird. Jenkins server can't connect to 64bit sshd, gets instant rejection:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not established!`

Weird part is I can connect to **both** services from my Linux machine.

Is is possible that service is installed wrongly? Should I blame Jenkins? ([issue 4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/4/))

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, why run a 32-bit and 64-bit sshd on the same system?

Comment: Because software we're developing is mainly designed for Linux. But to add support for windows user you can install cygwin and run this software. There is difference in 32bit Cygwin and 64bit Cygwin. So I'd like to have access to 32bit and 64bit bash (simply testing purposes).

Comment: don't you have any logs available on 64-bits sshd server?

Comment: When connection from Jenkins, log is empty, from Linux is everything fine. I tuned firewall on Windows and did some maintenance on Jenkins server and it works fine now. I believe it was bug in Jenkins (settings were not saved properly)